# Training LSTM with class imbalance

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I need to train an LSTM on some light curves, in order to find a signal (there are 2 classes signal and background). However the signal (data points corresponding to signal) is around 100 times less frequent than the background so I have a huge class imbalance and in the end all points are labelled as background. I tried to use focal loss, but it doesn't help. Is there a way to make it work?